# Move Top navigation menu and logo to the left

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to move my top navigation menu and logo to the left on my wordpress website.
I have tried several things, but I seriously lack CSS capabilities.
Can anybody please give a rookie like me a piece of advice?

Kind regards

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information about how to write good questions. You need to be more specific if you want anyone to help you.

Comment: I am completely new in this fora, and the setup confuses me quite a lot. I am not very experienced in working with Wordpress and CSS. I tried modifying "Rows" and "wrapper", but can't remember specifically what I did. As I mentioned, I am quite a CSS rookie :)